# implementing relationships between entity classes w/out ORM

Tags: java, database, design-patterns, dao

I have some entity classes that have one-to-one and/or one-to-many relationship with other entities.

I try to make a quite generic example that reflects my case... let's say that I have the following tables stored in a DB (no null values allowed):

```
   operations (ID, workerID, customerID, etc_etc)
      workers (ID, email, password, etc_etc)
    customers (ID, etc_etc)
 mobilePhones (workerID, phoneNumber)
```

It should be quite clear that:

- **1** operation has *only* **1** worker and **1** customer.
- **1** customer has *at least* **1** mobile phone number.

Thus I have the following entity classes:

```
public class Customer {
    private int id;
    //other fields, then constructors, getters and setters
}

public class Worker {
    private int id;
    //other fields
    private String[] mobilePhones;
}
```

As I already said in the title, **I can't use ORM** such as Hibernate, so I'm going to use DAOs.
*{ **EDIT:** I should have known you were curious to know why I can't use ORM... well, as I wrote in a comment down here:* It's an assignment (a project for a Software Engineering exam)*. }*

Now, I guess I'm not going to have any problem with `WorkerDAO`, that can easily manage the one-to-many relationship by selecting from `mobilePhones` all phone numbers where `workerID` equals the actual worker's id.

The real problem for me is how to manage the relationships between an `Operation` and its associate `Worker` and `Customer`.
Provided that I would like to avoid waste of memory, should I design my `Operation` entity like this:

```
public class Operation { // here I have some doubts
    private int id;
    private int workerId;
    private int customerId;
    //other fields
}
```

or maybe like this:

```
public class Operation { // here I have some doubts
    private int id;
    private Worker worker;
    private Customer customer;
    //other fields
}
```

?

The latter seems to be more *Object Oriented* but has one trivial implication: the instances of worker and customer must be in memory, even if the clients of `Operation` may not need them.

Even worse: if `OperationDAO` sets worker and customer as new Worker and Customer instances, this will lead to keep in memory *several instances referring to the same worker/customer* (e.g. two operations performed by the same worker).
Beside the waste of memory, this could definitely lead to *inconsistency of data* (e.g. one instance being modified without updating the others).

In order to avoid this, there should be introduced some class that is aware of which instances are currently loaded (e.g. using something like `List<Worker>`, `List<Customer>`, etc)... and honestly this seems to me to be an overkill.

I also thought I could try to implement some kind of *lazy fetching*, e.g. setting worker instance only at the first request, but still I would need some class that tracks what is in memory and what has to be queried; I wouldn't even know if this class should be related to *Data Access Logic* or to *Business Logic* (I'd guess the former but still not sure).

Anyway there's just no reason to implement all this, since I don't need a caching system (and I feel like it would seem much like that).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Just curious to know why can't you use ORM?

Comment: It's an assignment (a project for a Software Engineering exam).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Frameworks but you can use the patterns the frameworks themselves use. So I recommend you these solutions based on the [P of EAA. by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/)

1. You could use your first option **(Operation with workerId and customerId fields)** and use a [Row Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/rowDataGateway.html) for every entity (Operation, Worker, Customer).
   Now, if memory is an issue and your model requires it, keep control of all the Worker and Customer loaded instances with an [Identity Map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) and avoid reloading.
2. You could use your second option **(having an worker and customer instance in Operation)** and use a [Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) with [Lazy Load](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html) to load the instances only when required.

Worrying whether having multiple instances loaded or not depends on the type of application you are building and the scope of the instances; for instance, if you are a creating CRUD based application, you instances will normally have a request scope, so use the second approach and don't worry about memory waste or data inconsistencies.

Advice: Use interfaces to define your types.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which is for now the closest to the suggestions I was looking for.
I would like to implement something like Identity Map, but mainly in order to avoid data inconsistencies rather than to save memory.
I'm mostly worried about having in memory `worker1`, `operation1` and `operation2` that both refers to `worker1`; if user modifies `worker1`'s data, I should update as well `operation1` and `operation2`... this could be easily avoided if only `operation1` and `operation2` had the reference to `worker1` instead of having copies of it each in a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Spring JDBC or some other implementation of template method pattern. 1 DAO class per entity. Concerning the transaction issues, you can simply manage them yourself by calling setAutoCommit(false) on JDBC connection and handling the results of all queries.

good luck with reinventing the wheel though :]

Comment: Sorry, but I can't use Spring neither anything else. I hate to do so, but I _have to_ reinvent the wheel actually. :\

Answer (score 0):

Usually I would prefer

```
public class Operation { 
    private int id;
    private Worker worker;
    private Customer customer;
    //other fields
}
```

Since this is more object oriented and makes fetching easier. But since you are specifically distant from ORM (I don't know why???) so then it seems

```
public class Operation { 
    private int id;
    private int workerId;
    private int customerId;
    //other fields
}
```

to be a better choice and you can load the objects whenever you need.

ORM would have been the first choice... :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering to myself, lol.

With reference to the problem I explained in the comment of the answer of davidmontoyago, I thought that the simplest way to achieve my goal could be the following:

- having a class that tracks the instances that have been loaded from the DB and that are in memory. This could probably be a sort of utility class, I mean with private constructor and all static methods.
- ensure that all DAOs that return an instance of an entity class check if the requested instance is in the cache; if it is they return that instance, otherwise they load it from the DB and add it in the cache.

I try to sketch some code:

```
/* The class that will cache istances. */
static final class Cache { // package-private, so that only DAOs can see it.
    private static final int CAPACITY = 100; // max 100 istance per entity

    /* I will track each instance by its id, that is an Integer */
    private static Map<Integer,Worker> workers;
    private static Map<Integer,Customer> customers;
    private static Map<Integer,Operation> operations;

    private Cache() {} // I don't really need to istantiate this class

    // SOME OPERATIONS

    public static boolean isCached(Worker w);
    public static boolean isCached(Customer c);
    public static boolean isCached(Operation o);

    public static Worker getWorker(int id);
    public static Worker getCustomer(int id);
    public static Worker getOperation(int id);

    public static void addWorker(Worker w);
    public static void addCustomer(Customer c);
    public static void addOperation(Operation o);

}

class DAOWorkerImpl implements DAOWorker {
    public find(int id) {
        Worker w = null;
        if (Cache.isCached(id))
            w = Cache.getWorker(id);
        else {
            //retrieve worker
            Cache.addWorker(w);
        }
        return w;
    }
}
```

What do you think about it? It seems quite simple and it should do its job.

Btw while writing  this code, I thought that maybe it would be even better avoid writing the `Cache` class and to let manage all to their respective DAO (eg `DAOWorker` manages instances in memory of `Worker`, etc etc).

The only thing that doesn't convince me is that probably this would break the [Single Responsability Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)... what do you think about it?